# Pass route data as query string by URL routing

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have injected country code in URL and now want to pass country code route data as query string by URL routing.

```
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "Home",
        "{lang}",
        "~/Default.aspx?country={lang}"
    );
```

But it is not working and throwing error.

So, how could I append route data mean my country code with `Default.aspx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your case, appending query string parameters directly in the file path has no effect on getting the country code value you want.

I think what you can do instead is to make `country` as part of the route values.

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "Home",
    "Home/{country}", 
    "~/Default.aspx"
);
```

So essentially, you will have a route like `http://www.example.com/home/us`, and the value `us` can be retrieved by calling `Page.RouteData.Values["country"]` in the code behind.